# When appending button dynamically on table, unable to add onclick confirm event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I want to make a table that has cancel button in each rows.
When pressing this button and before the logic works I want to add an confirm event.
I searched on the web and found a post that its possible to add the confirm by putting onclick='return confirm("Cancel?");'  as an attribute inside the button.
However it didn't work since I have problem with the escape character.

--1st try

```
tr.append("<td><input type='button' class='cancelBtn' onclick='return 
confirm('Cancel?');' value='CancelButton'/></td>");
```

--2nd try

```
tr.append("<td><input type='button' class='cancelBtn' onclick='return 
confirm(\'Cancel?\');' value='CancelButton'/></td>");
```

I have tried to put escape character but it still didn't work. I have check the button on developer tool in chrome and both tries results are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use backticks (ES6 template strings). It's also best to use an intermediary function to handle the click and the `confirm`.

```js
function handleClick() {
  return confirm("Cancel?");
}

let tr = $("#tr");

tr.append(`<td><input type='button' class='cancelBtn' onclick='handleClick();' value='CancelButton'/></td>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr"></tr>
</table>
```

You could also just use `confirm` and avoid `return`:

```js
let tr = $("#tr");

tr.append(`<td><input type='button' class='cancelBtn' onclick='confirm("Cancel?");' value='CancelButton'/></td>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr"></tr>
</table>
```